# How to Test a function with Jest and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am new to jest and react and I need to write a unit test for this function, I have really tried to understand the documentation but I'm struggling to understand how I can accurately mock this function?

```
function desc(a, b, orderBy) {
if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
}
if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Also below this is my jest test which passes but has no assertions or line coverage

```
describe('Contract Table Ordering', () => {
 it('orders by desc', () => {
     contract.desc.mockImplementation(async () => { return (a, b, orderBy) 
=> (a[orderBy] > b[orderBy]) - (a[orderBy] <  b[orderBy]); });
 });
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock it? If you mock it then you're not testing it. Seems more like you'd want to call it with data then check that the data matches your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort a list/array of objects, you should do something like this:

Note that your both js file(sortFn.js) and unit-test file (sortFn.js) should be in the same folder.

```js
//in your js (sortFn.js) file: 
const sortTable = orderBy => {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (a[orderBy] > b[orderBy]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a[orderBy] < b[orderBy]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
export default sortTable;


//In your unit-test file (sortFn.test.js): 
import sortTable from  './sortFn';

describe('Contract Table Ordering', () => {
const originalArray = [{name: 'ab', age: 19}, {name: 'xz', age: 26}, {name: 'ab', age: 14}, {name: 'cw', age: 22}];
const expectedArray = [{name: 'xz', age: 26}, {name: 'cw', age: 22}, {name: 'ab', age: 19},{name: 'ab', age: 14}];

it('orders by desc', () => {
   const sortResult =  originalArray.sort(sortTable('age'));
   expect(sortResult).toEqual(expectedArray);
});
});
```

Comment: Whether or not they should be in the same folder depends on your project organization (personally I don't like having them in the same folder, that's a holdover from Java/Rails/Elixir days).

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with you, But it is only simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, as Dave said i needed to call it with data and then check if it matches,

```
 describe('Tests for the descendingOrderBy function', () => {
it('should reverse the full and part contracts', () => {
    const ordering = desc(fullObject, partContract, 'title');
    expect(ordering).toEqual(-1);
});
```